# Why i can't get rid the Facebook user-agent?

Tags: php, facebook, debugging, user-agent

I'd like to use some permalink slug that allow the users to share the link (url.com/artist/songtitle) with it's Facebook pictures, url, description, and so on (Which is redirect the users to url.com/#/artist/songtitle). So i decided to showing the OG meta to Facebook user-agent and separate it from the redirector.

[image: My code]

But, the problem come when i use the [Facebook Debug Tools](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) and try to fetch [it](http://music.warunganime.net/Aimer/Kimi%20wo%20Matsu). The crawlers wasn't caught by my user-agent separator.
[image: Whyyy???]

Im using, this code to detect Facebook crawlers. Any idea to fix this problem?

```
strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "facebookexternalhit/") || strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "Facebot"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out. Be careful when you're writing og:url meta, the crawlers would like to follow it. So, make sure the page you're write in og:url is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [`stristr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) or a `regex` instead of `strpos`. As it is right now, your code won't match `FacebookExternalHit`, because it contains Capital Letters and `strpos` function is `CaseSenSiTive`.

---

Facebook User-Agents are:

> ```
> FacebookExternalHit/1.0
> FacebookExternalHit/1.1
> facebookexternalhit/1.0 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
> facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
> facebookexternalhit/1.0 (+https://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
> facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+https://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
> ```

I'm using the code below to detect FB User-Agent in PHP and it works as intended:

```
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(stristr($agent, 'FacebookExternalHit')){
    //Facebook User-Agent
}else{
    //Other User-Agent
}
```

---

**Update:**

In order to know which user agents FB is using, try saving the user agent requests to a file, i.e.:

Example code to save UA requests:
Create a file named `ua_log.txt` with **write permissions**.

```
<?php
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
file_put_contents("$agent\n", "ua_log.txt", FILE_APPEND);
```

Use the **FB user agents** on `ua_log.txt` to create your filter.